# Thread-safe stack in Java with fixed capacity

Tags: java, multithreading, error-handling, thread-safety, stack

> Implement a multi-threaded stack, with freedom to use existing
>   implementations of stack. On top of being thread-safe, it must block
>   (not busy-wait) a pushing thread when stack is full and a popping
>   thread when stack is empty. It must signal the threads out of sleep
>   when stack has space again or elements to pop. Fairness is optional in this question.

How can I implement such a stack in Java? I came up with below implementation. Is this the correct way to solve above problem?

```
public class MyStack<E> {
  private final Stack<E> stack;
  private int max = 16;
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
  private final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
  private final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();

  public MyStack(int size) {
    this.stack = new Stack<>();
    this.max = size;
  }

  public void push(E e) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (stack.size() == max) {
        notFull.await();
      }
      stack.push(e);
      notEmpty.signalAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public E pop() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (stack.size() == 0) {
        notEmpty.await();
      }
      E item = stack.pop();
      notFull.signalAll();
      return item;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `Stack` a `java.util.Stack`? Isn't `java.util.Stack` already thread-safe?

Comment: Yes it is thread safe but I need to do some extra things on top of that as mentioned in my problem statement.

Comment: @200_success It's thread-safe, but not blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me on a cursory glance. It's pretty much the exact same code as in [java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) JavaDoc.

The only definitive problem I see is the catching and logging of `InterruptedException`. The code acts towards the caller as if the operation succeeded while nothing was done.

Not providing a way to set the maximum wait time will be a limitation in a library intended for generic use.

Stylistically, `private int max` should be final to emphasize that it must not be changed after initialization (as changing it when threads are waiting would cause serious problems).

Another thing, which may be a matter of taste, is the `stack.size() == max` comparison. I always like to use `>=` where a size is compared to a maximum limit (with a comment, of course). This gives an extra safeguard against infinite loops in the case where a programming error causes the collection to exceed maximum size.

Answer (score 1):

#### Guard Arguments

- `put` does not check for `e == null`. **Are null values allowed?** If not, add an argument guard `if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();`.

---

#### Naming Conventions

- Call your class `BlockingStack` to conform to Java naming guidelines concerning concurrent collections.
- `max` should be called `capacity`. A collection's capacity is its maximum size. As suggested in another answer, make it final. Also, since you set it in the constructor, there is no reason for the magic number `16`. It will always be overriden.
- The constructor takes a parameter `size` which you store to `max`. There is no reason to use different names. Both should be called `capacity` anyway.

---

#### Threading

- You silently catch `InterruptedException`. **This is bad design**. Exceptions should propagate up the call stack for callers to handle.
- Also, on exception, notify other threads waiting on the condition before throwing the exception up the call stack.
- Prefer `lockInterruptibly()` over `lock()`. [Discussed here](https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-reentrant-locks)
- The specification dictates fairness is optional. Let the consumer of the class specify a `boolean fair` in the constructor.

---

#### Refactored Code

```
public class BlockingStack<E> {

  private final Stack<E> stack;
  private final int capacity;
  private final ReentrantLock lock;
  private final Condition notEmpty;
  private final Condition notFull;

  public BlockingStack(int capacity) {
    this(capacity, false);
  }

  public BlockingStack(int capacity, boolean fair) {
    if (capacity <= 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.capacity = capacity;
    stack = new Stack<>();
    lock = new ReentrantLock(fair);
    notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
    notFull = lock.newCondition();
  }

  public void push(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (e == null)
      throw new NullPointerException();
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
      while (stack.size() == capacity) {
        notFull.await();
      }
      stack.push(e);
      notEmpty.signalAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException error) {
      notFull.signal();
      throw error;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public E pop() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
      while (stack.size() == 0) {
        notEmpty.await();
      }
      E item = stack.pop();
      notFull.signalAll();
      return item;
    } catch (InterruptedException error) {
      notEmpty.signal();
      throw error;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```